# Need help using when conditions with Ansible Loops

Tags: ansible

I am not able to skip tasks using when conditions with loops in Ansible. I don't see any skip output in the playbook task but it says skipped in the play recap.

My playbook tasks:

```
    - name: Capture the Existing DHCP Config
      set_fact:
        existing_dhcp_config: "{{ output['stdout'][0] | regex_findall('forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp \\S+') }}"

    - name: View the existing DHCP Config
      debug:
        var: existing_dhcp_config

    - name: Desired DHCP Config Based on Site Standards
      set_fact:
        desired_dhcp_config: "{{ lookup('file', './DHCP-Config/{{ inventory_hostname }}-dhcp.cfg') | regex_findall('forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp \\S+') }}"
    
    - name: View Desired DHCP Config
      debug:
        var: desired_dhcp_config

    - name: Compare Existing and Desired DHCP Configs to Remove Stale Config
      set_fact:
        dhcp_config_to_remove: "{{ existing_dhcp_config | difference(desired_dhcp_config) }}"

    - name: View the Difference Against Existing and Desired DHCP Configs
      debug:
        var: dhcp_config_to_remove
      when: dhcp_config_to_remove != ""

    - name: Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config
      junos_config:
        commands: delete {{ item }}
        comment: "{{ chg_ticket }}"
        confirm_commit: yes
      loop: "{{ dhcp_config_to_remove }}"
      when: dhcp_config_to_remove != ""

    - name: Verify the Final DHCP Config on JUNOS Devices
      junos_command:
        commands: show configuration | display set
      register: final_output

    - name: View the Final DHCP Config
      debug:
        msg: "{{ final_output['stdout'][0] | regex_findall('forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp \\S+') }}"
```

Output from the playbook:

```
TASK [Capture the Existing DHCP Config] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1]

TASK [View the existing DHCP Config] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1] => {
    "existing_dhcp_config": [
        "forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp 10.1.1.2"
    ]
}

TASK [Desired DHCP Config Based on Site Standards] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1]

TASK [View Desired DHCP Config] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1] => {
    "desired_dhcp_config": [
        "forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp 10.1.1.2"
    ]
}

TASK [Compare Existing and Desired DHCP Configs to Remove Stale Config] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1]

TASK [View the Difference Against Existing and Desired DHCP Configs] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1] => {
    "dhcp_config_to_remove": []
}

TASK [Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Verify the Final DHCP Config on JUNOS Devices] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1]

TASK [View the Final DHCP Config] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [junos-1] => {
    "msg": [
        "forwarding-options dhcp-relay server-group site-dhcp 10.1.1.2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
junos-1                : ok=23   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

In the following 2 tasks, I don't see any skipped descriptions in the play run even tough I have defined when statements for them:

```
TASK [View the Difference Against Existing and Desired DHCP Configs]
TASK [Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config]
```

Comment: There are 2 things you should check in ansible.cfg depending on your ansible version: for an old version your might have set`stdout_callback = skippy` (deprecated) that you can switch back to `default`. For more recent versions, you might have `display_skipped_hosts = no` that you have to turn back to yes.

Comment: on the Ansible documentation, it says that the default behavior is `display_skipped_hosts = yes`, actually it is not showing skipped with only the task with loop `TASK [Delete Non-Site Standards DHCP Config]` and for others it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Those two does not have a skipped statement because they do not skip explicitly.

In

```yaml
when: dhcp_config_to_remove != ""
```

you are checking that this variable is an empty **string**, which it is not, as it is an empty **list**:

```
ok: [junos-1] => {
    "dhcp_config_to_remove": []
}
```

So your condition is indeed not met, and the skip is actually coming from something else.

And as pointed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535458/need-help-using-when-conditions-with-ansible-loops#comment115874106_65535458), there is actually two possibility for an host to not show some skipped tasks:

1. You have an explicit skip via a conditional like `when`, but you have `display_skipped_hosts = no` in your configuration
2. You are looping on an empty list, so the task will be skipped and show no information, even with `display_skipped_hosts = yes`

So what you can do in here to make an explicit skip is to test the [`length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length) of your list

```yaml
when: dhcp_config_to_remove | length
```

As this test will yield a `0` for an empty list and that `0` evaluates to `False`; when any other number would evaluate to `True`, this will do the trick.

---

Still, when you loop on an empty list, the skip of the `loop` will happen before the skip of the `when`.

For example:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
      when: false
      loop: "{{ undefined_list | default([]) }}"
```

Yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: skipped worked for the first task but remains the same for the second task, displaying an empty prompt on the task but mentions skipped in play recap.

Comment: Seems indeed to be the case when you have an empty list, possibly because the `loop` is interpreted before the `when`

Comment: Is there a way to sort that out?